# "Failed to parse content to map" "Unexpected character '}'

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create mapping in Elasticsearch, however, it doesn't work. It seems to have some issues with `{`. I cannot find the cause of it, in my opinion it seems fine. Could you help me?

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/data?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 
'{
{
   "settings":{
      "number_of_shards":"1",
      "number_of_replicas":"1"
   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "data":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
               "title":{
                  "type":"text"
               },
               "sources":{
                  "type":"keyword"
               },
               "flags":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "null_value":"NULL"
               },
               "steps":{
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{
                     "Morning":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "null_value":"NULL",
                        "properties":{
                           "name":{
                              "type":"text"
                           },
                           "link":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "type":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "ingredients":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "flags":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "Evening":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "null_value":"NULL",
                        "properties":{
                           "name":{
                              "type":"text"
                           },
                           "link":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "type":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "ingredients":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           },
                           "flags":{
                              "type":"keyword",
                              "null_value":"NULL"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
}'
```

I am getting this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse content to map"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse content to map",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{ \"settings\": { \"number_of_shards\": \"1\", \"number_of_replicas\": \"1\", }, \"mappings\": { \"properties\": { \"data\": { \"type\": \"nested\", \"properties\": { \"title\": { \"type\": \"text\" }, \"sources\": { \"type\": \"keyword\" }, \"flags\": { \"type\": \"keyword\", \"null_value\": \"NULL\" }, \"steps\": { \"type\": \"nested\", \"properties\": { \"Morning\": { \"type\": \"nested\", \"null_value\": \"NULL\", \"properties\": { \"name\": {\"type\": \"text\"}, \"link\": {\"type\": \"keyword\", \"null_value\": \"NULL\"}, \"type\": {\"type\": \"keyword\", \"null_value\": \"\"[truncated 444 bytes]; line: 1, column: 70]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two opening curly braces `{` and two closing curly braces `}`, you need to remove one at the top and the other at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! It works now. However, I am getting an another error:
`"type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapping definition for [Evening] has unsupported parameters:  [null_value : NULL]"`

Can nested value have set `null_value`?

Comment: Not at the top level of the nested field definition, it doesn't make sens